# Is it possible to format case statement break keywords outside the braces with no indentation?

Tags: c++, clion

This is a requirement from my company's coding standards:

> The selection statement itself should be at the current indent level. Each option clause is then indented one level. The code associated with each option must be indented from the option clause itself. Further braces are used to clarify, these braces always appear on the line on their own. The break keyword is indented at the same level as the associated case keyword, it appears (when necessary) after the enclosing brace. See following example:
>
> ```
> switch (i)
> {
>     case 0:
>     {
>     }
>     /*
>     * Note - no break here - falls through
>     */
>     case 1:
>     {
>         printf ("Value is one or zero\n");
>     }
>     break;
>
>     case 2:
>     {
>         printf ("Value is %d\n", i);
>     }
>     break;
>
>     default:
>     {
>     /*
>     * There Must ALWAYS be a default, if the default is illegal then
>     * assert. (Make sure the control variable is logged)
>     */
>         assert_always ("What happened", i);
>     }
>     break;
> }
> ```

Given this information, I am struggling to find a way to configure this in CLion.

This is the `switch` I need to format for review:

```
switch (main_state)
{
    case fsm_definitions::STATE_INITIALISE:
    {
        output = main_state_initialise_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;

    case fsm_definitions::STATE_STARTUP:
    {
        output = main_state_startup_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;
    case fsm_definitions::STATE_READY:
    {
        output = main_state_ready_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;
    case fsm_definitions::STATE_CONNECTED:
    {
        output = main_state_connected_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;
    case fsm_definitions::STATE_MONITOR:
    {
        output = main_state_monitor_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;
    case fsm_definitions::STATE_EOL:
    {
        output = main_state_eol_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;
    case fsm_definitions::STATE_POWERING_OFF:
    {
        output = main_state_powering_off_fsm::handle_event (event);
    }
        break;
    default:
    {
        output = false;
    }
        break;
}
return output;
```

As you can see, the `break`s get improperly indented. I can remove the indentation manually, but format on save replaces them where they are now. I have tried <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> in the "Code Style" settings for "case", "switch", "break", etc, in several sections including "Tabs and Indents", "Spaces", "Wrapping and Braces", "Blank Lines".

I don't want to have to switch editors any time I want to save that file for review. How can I force the formatter to indent the `break` outside the braces according to my coding standards documentation?

Comment: As an aside, I see nothing in this which indicates the braces are necessary.

Comment: @Chris Often code formatting practices are not strictly necessary but are rather intended to provide clarity and coherence/consistency.

Comment: Not that this rule actually does provide either clarity, coherence, or consistency. `break` is part of the 'code associated with each option', so these rules give two mutually contradictory indent levels for it, and also for whether it should be enclosed in or excluded from any braces. I've seen lots of ways of formatting `case` statements in my time, but this is a new one on me, and the worst. I'm not surprised your IDE can't cope with it. If they can't come up with an IDE configuration that implements their self-inconsistent standard they should change their standard. Not your problem.

Comment: why not having break; inside the blocks?

Comment: ... where everybody else puts them? @battlmonstr

Comment: Yeah I don't get to set the standard I just have to follow it. Incidentally, I found a way to do it with Clang formatter. I'll write an answer about what I did when I had time in case there are others with this problem.